# Fast report does not print

Tags: c#, fastreport

I have a problem. I use this code :

```
 Report report = new Report();
 report.Load("sample.fpx");

 report.Print();`
```

I see the print dialog, click "Print", but no document will be printed? What's the problem?

Comment: It may be problem with your printer or report itself, try to `report.ShowPrepared();` and print from menu, or export to some format(e.g. PDF) and print produced pdf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
report.LoadPrepared("sample.fpx"); //load prepared report
```

Load method is for templates.

Answer (score 0):

You should prepare report before printing